# Repeated linear programming with similar (not identical) problems

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I have multiple linear programming problems of the form:

$$
Minimize\{c^{T}\cdot x\} s.t. Ax = b, x \ge 0
$$

Where $c$ and $A$ are fixed for all the problems. Is there any way to utilize that for a more efficient solution than solving each problem from scratch?

Currently I'm using [scipy's linprog](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html#scipy.optimize.linprog) but the performance is too slow given the amount of problems (thousands). I was wondering if there's a way to make this feasible with some smart preprocessing.
I've tried searching using terms such as "repeated linear programming", "repeated simplex" etc., but to no avail.

Comment: For future reference, I've asked this question on [math overflow](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3794332/repeated-linear-programming-with-similar-not-identical-problems/3794351#3794351) where it was proposed to search for warm-start LP solvers and use the dual simplex algorithm.